# Is there a prefered Modulation Index with Pulse Amplitude Modulation? (PAM)

Tags: modulation, pulse, amplitude

You can vary the modulation index of Pulse Analogue Modulation. For instance, the RF carrier could be 100% modulated on marks, and zero % on spaces. Or, 100% on marks, 50% on spaces. In theory you could set whatever modulation percentage you like on both the marks and the spaces.

But, is the preferred modulation index 1, that is full carrier on marks, and no carrier on spaces? Is that the usual case when employing PAM? I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: I actually wonder if the term "modulation index" makes any real sense with PAM. If you can independently set mark and space carrier levels.

Comment: hm, if you set it to 0 or 100% power, you end up with OOK (which isn't really ASK, imho, but that might subject to individual definition). OOK is indeed widely used because it's so damn easy to generate, but it's significantly more error-prone than e.g. BPSK, at the same number of bits per symbol, but with worse analog effects. Indeed, the error probability of a non-OOK ASK should be WORSE than that of OOK, which explains *why* no-one does ASK (unless they're dealing with short distances of constant cabling and would rather have digital baseband then sensibly modulated signal. ethernet.)

Comment: I might have had a misunderstanding about PAM. I believe it is a analogue modulation technique. It's a modulation technique used when an analog signal is sampled, and the individual samples used to modulate the rf carrier. My question as posed mixed marks and spaces with PAM. And that I think was an error on my part. So, I think there is an error in the question itself.

Comment: Actually, there's not a problem with the question as such. But with my comments.

Comment: Consider that modulation gain is inverted like analog TV so max input (white level) determines how close to zero carrier one gets from under or over modulation (undesirable).  Thus steep compression.  TV used 10 IRE as I recall for white.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are really asking about the levels of amplitude shift keying (ASK) or modulation.

It should be obvious that the larger the difference between the amplitude levels, the higher the signal to noise ratio will be.  Obviously then, full 100%, also called on/off keying (OOK), yields the best signal to noise ratio within the overall ASK scheme.

Comment: Yes, I've been mixing PAM with ASK. I know what PAM is, but then I began to introduce marks and spaces, which is a modulation technique associated with keying. You do not key with PAM.

Comment: I believe the answer to my question would be, the preferred modulation index with PAM is 1.

Comment: My question can still be answered in terms of PAM.

Answer (score 1):

It is preferred to use an index of 1 for binary , most commonly used in fibre channels.

For lower index values, it more optimal to use 4, 8 or 16 levels to compress video bandwidth.

e.g. a system, known as 8VSB, is based on a three-level PAM like 100BASE-TX, but uses addition of VSB.

Comment: As a note: I have a modicum of appreciation of amplitude modulation from my amateur radio days. So, this explains why I asked about modulation index. But, of course PAM is something very different from regular AM. Because you can mess with the amplitude levels, and the number of them. and I suppose introduce coding. Which I suppose makes a question about modulation index not quite the thing it is if I were asking in relation to regular AM.

Comment: Audio AM SNR improves with m but if m>1 then distortion automatically rises with m-1. So compander curves are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It *depends*, if you use more levels then you can send more bits per second. And at the same time you lower the SNR ratio. You can take care of that by encoding your message and decoding with [error correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_detection_and_correction). This means that you will send more bits than you actually need to. Then on the receiver side, some bits are wrong, but you got some extra bits which helps you to reconstruct the original message. Or at least indicate that an error has occurred => you should ask for the message again.

You can however compress the data before you encode it with error correction. So in *some* cases you will send less or equal number of bits as if you didn't use compression and error correction. But this means there'll be some overhead, some delays here and there.

In the end it depends on your channel, is your channel noisy, such as sending data through space to Mars or some other place in space. Then you would probably only want OOK, as Olin says, yields best SNR. You would also want to use OOK together with some error correction code. 
[Hadamard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_code#History) was used 1971 for the [Mariner 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariner_9) mission to correct for picture transmission errors

But if the input and output share the same wire. A physical wire. Then the noise is severely reduced (compared to wireless) and you can afford to use more levels and this way send more bits. It doesn't have to be a wire, but that's one example of a low noise channel.

---

Bottom line: It depends.